# scroll fixed header

Tags: html, css

Is there anyone who knows how to create this layout [ms ie page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/download-ie). What im trying to accomplish is a fixed header but when the page is minimized the whole page can be scrolled to the right including the fixed header does anyone know how todo this, is it all done in css? All im able todo is have a fixed header and scroll just the content but I want to scroll the header aswell when its a centain width

Comment: You can try adding a fixed-width `<div>` inside your fixed header.

Comment: Downvote for question without any code

Comment: @KDM Try my suggestion if that's what you wanted. And next time try to put some effort from your side before seeking help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly, you want to have a fixed header and scroll only the content and when the page is resized to a smaller width, you want the header to scroll as well. Am I right?

To do this, you should set `position: fixed` for the header. Then using @media query you should specify the max-width for which the header should lose its **fixed** property.

```
Markup:

<div class="header">
Header content goes here
</div>

Style:

.header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 500px){
  .header{
     position: relative;
   }
}
```